# Should I/Do I need to sign foreign DLLs?

Tags: windows, dll, code-signing

I'm developing an electron application which depends on a bunch of modules that use native (C/C++) code.
Due to the way electron includes a patched node.js, these native modules have to be recompiled from source (everything is OSS) when we prepare a release.

One problem we have is that for a small number of users those native modules fail to load with pretty unspecific error messages. The modules don't have any further dependencies and we do validate at startup that all files shipped with the application are there.
So the only reason I can think of why the modules don't load is that some Anti-Virus may interfere with the loading of those modules (they are dlls but with a different file extension).

Since the modules were recompiled, even if the prebuild ones had been signed, the ones we ship are not.

So my question is: Does it make sense for us to sign all those dlls we ship with our own certificate, even though they aren't developed by us? Are there potential (legal) ramifications for using a certificate like that?
Is my theory about AV interfering with the loading of DLLs even plausible?

Comment: It's questionable whether implementing any 'solution' is a reasonable approach to solving a problem you do not understand.

Comment: Well yes, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong, ruling out potential causes is part of that. Hence my question whether there is a potential drawback.
Since AVs work with highly dynamic data it's almost impossible to reproduce these kinds of problems, I haven't even been able to reproduce some problems where I know it's the AV, what AV it was, its settings and had the exact same version of the virus database. These things are just completely non-deterministic, random black boxes.

Comment: Jumping to conclusions without performing even cursory analysis isn't prudent. Have you considered enabling [loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps) to at least find out, which modules failed to load and why?

Comment: I'm not jumping to conclusion, I'm considering a way to narrow down the problem that hopefully has no negative impact. Maybe this wasn't clear but this isn't a problem that I can reproduce, it happens to a (seemingly random) handful of users out of hundreds of thousands and often only for a very limited amount of time so even if the users were willing and had the technical knowledge, working with them to narrow down the problem would likely not work.
And yes, I know exactly which module fails to load and no, I don't know why, that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @Tannin: Did you try it? Did it help?